# Release memory from 2 different DLLs

Tags: c++, memory-management, dll, release

I have 2 dynamic library: dllA and dllB

dllA puts (char* type) to 1 function of dllB and this function alloc memory for `char* type` and return result to dllA.

**DLLB:**

```
getResult(char *rs)
{
     // calculate to get length
     rs = new char[lenght];
     rs = .... // do something here
}
```

dllA get result, do something with output and release rs.

**DLLA:**

```
getResult(char *rs);
std::cout << rs;
// can not release rs here
if(rs){
     delete []rs;
} // crash here
```

But I can not release `char* type` maybe because memory of `char* type` is in memory from dllB and we can not access to this memory space.

**If I build with debug-mode, it works normally. And it causes error with release-mode**

Comment: Typically, you need to free memory in the same module it was allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Each DLL typically implements its own heap tracking so memory allocated by one DLL must be deallocated by the same DLL. This is typically done by providing a corresponding free function. I.e. in your example above you might do the following (also note that the rs parameter must be passed as a pointer to a pointer so that we can return a value in it):

**DllB :**

```
void getResult(char **rs)
{
     // calculate to get length
     *rs = new char[lenght];
     rs = .... // do something here
}
void freeResult(char* rs)
{
    delete [] rs;
}
```

**DllA :**

```
getResult(char *rs);
std::cout << rs;
freeResult(rs); // don't crash here :-)
```

To make sure DllA always calls freeResult you can wrap it in a smart pointer such as the boost::shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr (though I haven't tested std::shared_ptr):

**DllB :**

```
char* getResult()
{
     // calculate to get length
     char* rs = new char[length];
     rs = .... // do something here
     return rs;
}
void freeResult(char* rs)
{
    delete [] rs;
}
```

**DllA :**

```
shared_ptr<char> rs(getResult(), freeResult);
std::cout << rs;
// no need to free rs here, the shared_ptr will do it automatically.
```

Comment: Thanks,SketchyLizard.It 's useful for me.

Comment: This is not typical, precisely because of the hassle produced.

Answer (score 0):

The memory manager on Windows is part of the C runtime library, so if both DLLs use the same C runtime library for their `new[]`/`delete[]` calls, it works just fine: both calls are done in different DLLs, but they both use the same copy of the CRT DLL which does the allocation/deallocation.

In case you cannot guarantee that this is always the case, it's better to change the API so that allocation & deallocation happens in the same case. For instance, your "dllB" could expose a `freeResult` function which just does `delete[]` and which is supposed to be called on the value returned by `getResult`.

Answer (score 0):

What i think is you are passing `rs` to function `getResult` by value becuase of which rs in the dllA function doesnt contain the valid address of memory allocated. Can you pass reference of the `rs` to `getResult`.

so function will look like following in dllB:

```
getResult(char* &rs)
{
     // calculate to get length
     rs = new char[lenght];
     rs = .... // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DLLs are built against different C runtimes (for example `debug` vs. `release`) you need to delete the memory in the same DLL you allocated it.

We usually solve this by providing a `deleteResult` method:

**Dll B:**

```
deleteResult(char *rs) {
  delete[] rs;
}
```

**Dll A:**

```
getResult(rs);
std::cout << rs;
// can not release rs here
if(rs) {
  deleteResult(rs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical solution is to use *one* memory allocator. Usually, that's the DLL version of the CRT. When you're using Microsoft COM, it's `IMalloc` or equivalently `CoTaskMemAlloc/Free`. A few of the answers suggest using a per-DLL deallocation function. That works, but is a major pain.